# setting up load balancing with mwan3 on openwrt

Tags: openwrt

I want my traffic going through USB-tethering, while destination to 192.168.0.0/24 going to WAN port. I have SSH-ed into the GL-AR750S and opkg-install-ed luci-app-mwan3. Both interfaces are up and accessible to the Internet. However, there is no network access (LAN or Internet) when the 0.0.0.0/0 default rule is set going through tethering_only.

OpenWRT MWAN Interfaces
https://ibb.co/LP5q8qB

OpenWRT MWAN Members
https://ibb.co/DfSb4vD

OpenWRT MWAN Policies
https://ibb.co/XDNdK5t

OpenWRT MWAN Rules
https://ibb.co/2YzP9nN

Routes
https://ibb.co/XzKKmS9

MWAN Status - Detail
https://pastebin.com/cLGWJs1y

MWAN Status - Troubleshooting
https://pastebin.com/vNW7JReE

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a real nice tutorial on how to accomplish this at:
https://github.com/tiagonmas/ar-750-use-lan-port-as-2nd-wan.md

It looks like the only files you need to edit are the */etc/config/network* and the */etc/config/mwan3* files (and adjust the firewall from the GUI).